# The Killing form on the Lie algebra of a compact connected Lie group, is it nondegenerate?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group and $Z(G)$ be the center of $G$. By definition, the commutator subgroup, $G'$, is the normal subgroup of $G$ generated by $\lbrace g_1g_2{g_1}^{-1} {g_2}^{-1} \vert g_i \in G\rbrace $.

Theorem 5.22 in the book "compact Lie groups" by Sepanski tells us that $G= G'Z(G)^0$,  $Z(G') = G' \cap Z(G)$  is a finite abelian group (i.e $G'$ is semisimple), $Z(G)^0$ is a torus, and $$G \cong [G' \times Z(G)^0]/F,$$

where the finite abelian group $F= G' \cap Z(G)^0$ is embedded in $G' \times Z(G)^0$ as $\lbrace (f,f^{-1}) \vert f \in F \rbrace.$

$\textbf{Question :}$ It is well known that if $G$ is a compact semisimple Lie group, then the killing form on its Lie algebra is nondegenerate. What can we say about the killing form if $G$ is a compact connected Lie group? (I don't know if the above theorem implies that it is nondegenerate in this case as well).

Comment: It's not, e.g. $G$ could be a torus.

Comment: Seconding @QiaochuYuan's point: we'd need trivial center to have non-degenerate Killing form in a compact real Lie group...

Comment: Note by Cartans criterion that a Lie algebra has nondegenerate Killing form if and only if it is semisimple. Meanwhile the Lie algebra of a compact group has negative semidefinite Killing form. Combined these give you the result that the Lie algebra of a compact semisimple Lie group is negative definite